# extracting data from two columns

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame that looks like this.
It refers to words and their structure

`df <- data.frame(word = c("pokkoitta", "demna", "ningatinggo ", "tengkeam", "bampana", "njam"), structure = c("CvC:vvC:v", "CvCCv", "CvCvCvNCv", "CvNCvvC", "CvNCvCv"  , "NCvC"))`

The second column indicates the structure of the first column. If in the second column a C:, NC or CC combination occurs, I need to extract from the first column, which these refer to.

So I would need:

`kk    C:
kk    C:
mn    CC
ngg   NC
ngk   NC
mp    NC
nj    NC`

One thing that needs to be taken into account is that a simple count does not work on 2 letters in the left column, which correspond to 1 letter in the right columne, namely ng|sy|kh = C (not CC, as they represent one phoneme)
Also, in one word, more than one of these combinations can occur

Thx

Update:

This would be the matching pattern with regex:

```
(nj|ngk|ngg|nc|nt|nd|mp|mb) = NC
(ng|sy|kh) = C    
[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])\\1+) = C:
([b-df-hj-np-tv-z]) = C
(') = :    
((a|e|i|o|u)\\1+) = v:    
(a|e|i|o|u)  = v
```

Comment: Add a sample data set and also list the matching rules in order between the letters

Comment: Can't you use whatever tool was used for finding the structures? I don't think there is a simple regex solution to this, as the lengths don't match one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I might have just re-invented the algorithm used to find those structures, but it seems to work.

```
df <- data.frame(
  word=c("pokkoitta", "demna", "ningatinggo", "tengkeam", "bampana", "njam"),
  structure=c("CvC:vvC:v", "CvCCv", "CvCvCvNCv", "CvNCvvC", "CvNCvCv", "NCvC"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

pat <- data.frame(str=c("NC", "C", "C:", "C", "v:", "v"),
                  rex=c("nj|ngk|ngg|nc|nt|nd|mp|mb",
                        "ng|sy|kh",
                        "([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])\\1+",
                        "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]",
                        "(a|e|i|o|u)\\1+",
                        "a|e|i|o|u"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

xs <- xw <- df[,1]
for (i in 1:nrow(pat)) {
    rx <- gregexpr(pat[i, 2], xs)
    mc <- regmatches(xs, rx)
    mp <- sapply(mc, function(x) format(paste("", x), width=6))
    mc[lengths(mc) != 0] <- mp[lengths(mc) != 0]
    regmatches(xw, rx) <- mc
    regmatches(xs, rx) <- paste("", format(pat[i, 1], width=5))
}

phon <- trimws(cbind(word=xw, structure=xs))
phon <- apply(phon, 1, strsplit, " +")
phon <- lapply(phon, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))
head(phon, 3)
# [[1]]
#      word structure
# [1,] "p"  "C"      
# [2,] "o"  "v"      
# [3,] "kk" "C:"     
# [4,] "o"  "v"      
# [5,] "i"  "v"      
# [6,] "tt" "C:"     
# [7,] "a"  "v"      
# 
# [[2]]
#      word structure
# [1,] "d"  "C"      
# [2,] "e"  "v"      
# [3,] "m"  "C"      
# [4,] "n"  "C"      
# [5,] "a"  "v"      
# 
# [[3]]
#      word  structure
# [1,] "n"   "C"      
# [2,] "i"   "v"      
# [3,] "ng"  "C"      
# [4,] "a"   "v"      
# [5,] "t"   "C"      
# [6,] "i"   "v"      
# [7,] "ngg" "NC"     
# [8,] "o"   "v"
```